# android: run cmd on server

Tags: android, cmd

i want run command line on server from android application to see the processor usage, hard disk usage, and ram usage, to notify android app's user

i have server access, but i don't know how to run command on server from application
and all of theme must run without any api if not possible we can create 1 or 2 api(s)

i just check ping of server from mobile devices, but i can't run cmd yet
thanks for your help

that's the cmd line to get processor usage:

```
wmic cpu get loadpercentage
```

Answer (score 0):

That command doesn't work in Android. It is a Windows command.

Comment: from android device connect to server and run this command, and get result and show result on application